# Magento saveOrderAction() ajax response xx{"success":true,"error":false}

Tags: ajax, magento, magento-1.7, checkout

I am using Magento `Community 1.7.2`, and when I hit the confirm order button `saveOrder` response is `xx{"success":true,"error":false}` and it is not redirecting to the success page. Anyone have any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Where is the actual question and what does this have to do with Google Analytics ?

Comment: its not redirecting to success page so the sales are not getting registered in analytics, and my question is what can be causing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem starting last Friday. I implemented the following solution and it removed the xx from the output:

http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/tag/onepage-checkout-issue/

Also, run a scan at the following: https://shoplift.byte.nl/ - this may have had something to do with my problem. Still figuring that one out.

Comment: this worked great, but the transactions still not getting registed in analytics

Comment: Sometimes eCom data is delayed - give it some time if you made the change recently. In the meantime check the source for the GA eCom code.

Comment: i know, it has almost an hour of delay, the problem was that i replaced the line that send de data to analytics when trying to fix the xx issue